# Can I use System.Reflection.Emit to build a constructor for an existing type?

Tags: c#

Does c# have support for building a constructor using a `DynamicMethod`? Consider this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

I would like to create a new constructor for `Foo` that takes no arguments, and compile it as a `Func<Foo>`. For example:

```
DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("NewInitializer", typeof(Foo), Type.EmptyTypes);
ILGenerator il = dyn.GetILGenerator();

LocalBuilder loc0 = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Foo));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, loc0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

Func<Foo> newInitFunc = (Func<Foo>)dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo>));
Foo f = newInitFunc();
```

Note, this is just one of the implementations I have tried. Everything ends up throwing an `AccessViolationException`:

> Operation Could Destabilize the Runtime

when I call the method. Is it even possible to create a constructor using a `DynamicMethod`?

Comment: I think you should use [ConstructorBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.constructorbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @dotctor This would be a constructor to an existing type, not `TypeBuilder`. I realized my question title was unclear about this, I have edited.

Comment: @EliArbel I realize this process would not be adding a constructor to the type, as this would require modding the CLR method table. I only wish to create a `DynamicMethod` that emulates a constructor in its CIL

Comment: @EliArbel I need this to quickly initialize an instance of the type, bypassing high-overhead code that exists in the default constructor. `FormatterServices` could be the solution though.

Comment: @EliArbel `GetUninitializedObject()` runs about 15-25x slower than calling ctor. Something else I tried that runs a little faster (still not as fast as ctor): create one instance with `GetUninitializedObject()`, then call `MemberwiseClone()` to create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

If inheriting from those types is possible, you could create a class using Emit that inherits from the the existing type and doesn't call the base constructor.

```
var typeToLoad = typeof(Foo);
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Dynamic"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Dynamic");
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeToLoad.Name, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.AutoClass, typeToLoad);
// create a constructor that doesn't call the base constructor
var constructorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName | MethodAttributes.SpecialName, CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes);
var ilGenerator = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
// create a factory method so we could create a delegate for it
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Create", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeBuilder, Type.EmptyTypes);
ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, constructorBuilder);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var generatedType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var factory = (Func<Foo>)generatedType.GetMethod("Create", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo>));
```

This runs as fast as the `new` operator.